# Why does it highlight the whole div easily when I click on space css php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Do you have any css code to stop this highlight thing on chrome. Usually, we quickly double click on space of a website, it will highlight the whole div, but my website is very easy to be highlight, so I want to know do I have to put some css code, something like text-decoration:none, help, appreciate.

Comment: any code? HTML code you are doing? screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`user-select:`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/) CSS property:

```
div {
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
    -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
    -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */

    /* No support for these yet, use at own risk */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
}
```

Comment: You are certainly welcome. Happy coding!